# If contents of <div> are clicked, register as the <div> being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that sits within a `div` (it's a small button):

```
<div>
    <img src=''/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make it so that if either the cursor clicked the `img` part of the `div` or the `div` part of it, that it will always register as the `div` part being clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) is a [bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) event which means when a click happens in a descendant element it will be propagated to the parent elements unless it is stopped by an element's handler(by calling [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation))

Comment: @frosty there the problem is [e.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will refer to the element which triggered the event... so if you click in the `img` it will refer to the `img` elemnet

Comment: @frosty are you using jQuery in your project

Comment: @frosty then use jQuery, it is pretty easy there - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r3612x2j/1/